# Logic? Debugged multiple times and cant find the error

Tags: java, for-loop, logic, logical-operators

In this program I retrieve a list of high and low temps from a .txt file (file below) In the first for loop I separate the high and low temperatures into a 2D array, than I created a `getLowTemp()` and `getHighTemp()` method so I could get the highest and lowest temperatures from one dimension, But when I compile and run it I get the wrong input, I've ran both for loops through the debugger multiple times, and can not find the reason, can anyone tell me why my two methods are not working?

text.txt file

```
JAN 48 2
FEB 53 6
MAR 57 30
APR 54 34
MAY 73 37
JUN 85 52
JUL 91 59
AUG 87 61
SEP 81 49
OCT 63 38
NOV 61 29
DEC 52 17
```

Temperature class

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temperature 
{
static String fileName, line;
static int high;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    int[][] temps = new int[12][2];
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("text.txt"));
    for(int i=0;i<temps.length;i++) 
    {
       String months = scanner.next();
       int high = scanner.nextInt();
       temps[i][0] = high;
       int low = scanner.nextInt();
       temps[i][1] = low;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(temps)); //printed the whole array to make sure placed correctly
    int highestTemp = getHighTemp(temps);
    System.out.println("Highest Temp: " + highestTemp);
    int lowestTemp = getLowTemp(temps);
    System.out.println("Lowest Temp: " + lowestTemp);


}


public static int getHighTemp(int[][] arr) 
{
    int high = arr[0][0];
    for(int i = 0; i<11;i++){
        int nextValue =  arr[i+1][0];
        if(high < nextValue)
            high = nextValue;
        else
            high = arr[i][0];
    }
    return high;

}


public static int getLowTemp(int[][] arr) 
{
    int low = arr[0][0];
    for(int i = 0; i<11;i++)
    {
        int nextValue =  arr[i+1][0];

        if(low > nextValue)
            low = nextValue;
        else
            low = arr[i][0];
    }
    int lowestValue = low;
    return lowestValue;

}
```

}

Comment: It worked without any errors. I've got following in output:
[[48, 2], [53, 6], [57, 30], [54, 34], [73, 37], [85, 52], [91, 59], [87, 61], [81, 49], [63, 38], [61, 29], [52, 17]]
Highest Temp: 61
Lowest Temp: 52

Comment: @DanishAmjad Highest temp should be 91, because it is only supposed to go through values from [0-11][0] , 61 is in [0-11][1]

Comment: What I mean is I want the highest input in [0-11][0], I don't want to check the 3rd column for anything, I just strictly want the 2nd row only @DanishAmjad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main problems with your logic.
 1. You are constantly updating your low/high goal in an else statement in for loop. If you remove them you get the right answer.

2.You are searching lowest value in high values column. So using arr[i][1] solved it too.

```
public static int getHighTemp(int[][] arr) 
{
    int high = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i<12;i++){
        if(high<arr[i][0])
            high = arr[i][0];
    }
    return high;
}

public static int getLowTemp(int[][] arr) 
{
    int low = 665456456;
    for(int i = 0; i<12;i++){
        if(low>arr[i][1])
            low = arr[i][1];
    }
    return low;

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for, could you tell me what was wrong with mine?

Comment: The problem is exactly the code what I comment out In my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
      public static int getHighTemp(int[][] arr) // get highest from all the highest
      {
        int high = arr[0][0];
        for(int i = 0; i<11;i++){
          int nextValue =  arr[i+1][0];
          if(high < nextValue)
            high = nextValue;
    //      else
    //        high = arr[i][0];
        }
        return high;
      }


      public static int getLowTemp(int[][] arr) // get lowest from all the highest
      {
        int low = arr[0][0];
        for(int i = 0; i<11;i++)
        {
          int nextValue =  arr[i+1][0];
          if(low > nextValue)
            low = nextValue;
    //      else
    //        low = arr[i][0];
        }
        int lowestValue = low;
        return lowestValue;
      }
```

Comment: This is still incorrect - the second subscript in getLowTemp() should be 1 - ie. `int low = arr[0][1]` and so on through the method.

Comment: It is meant to be [0][0] Matt, I want to find the lowest value in that index, I will make  a separate method for the other column @MattPearce

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I missed that in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing quickly your code, you must have an array out of bound exception I think:

```
for(int i = 0; i<11;i++){
        int nextValue =  arr[i+1][0];
```

Your array lenth is 12 (0->11) but with i+1 you are out of 11 (11+1)

Then you parse the same value in getHighTemp and getLowTemp, always the high.

Comment: No errors? I fixed that earlier now Im just trying to fix this current problem

Answer (score 0):

You have a logic error in your method - you assume that if the next value isn't higher or lower than the current then the current value must be the highest/lowest. For this reason your result is always the last-but-one value in the array. So:

```
if (high < nextValue) 
    high = nextValue
// else
//     high = arr[i][0];
```